# Django | Why use {% load static %} and make template compiler work more?

Tags: django, django-templates

For static resources like images/CSS/Js I can directly use their path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/default.min.css">
#in app level templates:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/myapp/css/app.min.css">
```

why add clutter to the template with:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/default.min.css' %}" />
```

unless you are dynamically adding part of the path or version at the end of url.
I suspect templates with {% load static %} would be less performant(may be ignorable, but still why?)

Please kindly enlighten me, i think there might be a strong reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hard Coding it like that can create a few problems in production.
Instead it's a good idea to create `static` root in the settings and always use that. Further more if django knows it's a static file, it will not only look in the "hard coded" location but in other possible locations too.

Comment: ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root', 'static')```   I would still set these setting even in my case <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/myapp/css/app.min.css">  this linked file in django project structure would in app/myapp/static/app/css/app.min.css and it would work, we know this. How is this even hard coding?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you kinda answered your own question when you said unless you are dynamically adding part of the path, which is exactly what you are doing. And there is a strong reason too.

> The 'static' is your STATIC_URL. Forget the static_root, it's a place where you "collectstatic" and then move it to a production location.

I have a Saas django portal deployed somewhere, in production my STATIC_URL (yea 'static' becomes the following:

> https://some-cdn-somewhere.com/me-static-assets/static/ I let some performant CDN serve static assets after moving the collected files to it somehow.

For emphasis, I do this for performance and you may decide to use a web server like nginx to serve static assets, they are static afterall and nginx is extremely performant for such. Typically you configure your static url and let nginx serve that one from a folder (STATIC_ROOT) and proxy the other urls to say gunicorn.

Consider the well written django docs for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: So, if i am not using any CDN or not hosting statics external to django the following should be more performant, right? ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/default.min.css">
#in app level templates:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/myapp/css/app.min.css"> ```

Comment: Probably, but your question is why static. If you change your mind and decide to serve static files in another way later, the clutter will come to the rescue and will let you switch easily.